# When removing Ubuntu for windows should I delete all partitions?

Tags: windows, uninstall, partitioning

I'm about to install Windows 10 from a usb. Currently the only operating system on my computer is Ubuntu. I want to remove Ubuntu for windows 10 and probably create a dual boot at a later time.

When I am in the installer Page for windows 10 regarding portions should I delete all of the partitions for the drive I am installing to? In this case it is the SSD that Ubuntu is currently installed on.

There are 3 partitions. One 215gb, one 512mb and one 7.9gb. The drive is meant to be 240gb.

Comment: What is type of your 215 gb partition fat or ext. Post output of `fdisk -l`.

Comment: Output: http://pastebin.com/psKwrZsL

Comment: it seems your ssd is gpt partitioned, open up `gparted` and tell type of your partitions on ssd(`/dev/sda`). If its `fat` windows will recognize it right away else you could shrink it and and make a new partition for windows.

Comment: There is a fat32 flagged as boot (512mb) the 215gb as ext4 and the 7.9 is a linux-swap. I really just want to remove Ubuntu from it to install Windows on it's own for now not on a separate partition

Comment: Ok you could do that very easily, just make sure you have backup of your data in you ssd and then just remove every partition from ssd at install time in windows(boot,linux swap and 215 gb one). Windows installation setup will take care of rest itself.

Answer (score -1):

You will want to remove all partitions from the install disk, yes. Windows will create its own partition (or two, depending if it wants a D: drive). When installing Ubuntu later, you will recreate 2 more partitions.

Beware that you will lose ALL data on the Ubuntu partitions. Make sure you've saved your documents, pictures, videos, etc. before doing this.

Comment: Is there a reason this is downvoted?

Comment: I'd like to know why as well. The OP wants to dualboot "at a later time," so wouldn't he want to remove all partitions at this time and have Windows configure its partitions as it wants?

When downvoting, please provide some reasons!